# linking from one server to another but keeping the same domain name

Tags: html, dns, named

I have a splash page hosted at `www.someserver.com` and I'm looking to have one link on the page lead to a site hosted on another server, `www.anotherserver.com`. I probably need to keep these on distinct servers for the time being.

I'm hoping to have the whole thing appear under a a single company domain, `www.company.com`, and to have it so that when a user clicks on this link, you see neither `www.someserver.com` nor `www.anotherserver.com`, just `www.company.com`.

I know that I can set up some kind of domain masking (we're using GoDaddy for our hosting), but I'm worried that clicking out to `www.anotherserver.com` is going to keep this from all appearing under the same domain.

Is there a way to set this up so that links from and to both of these servers appear as `www.company.com`?

Comment: Is your first requirement of displaying the splash page available at www.someserver.com server under www.comapny.com done?

Answer (score 0):

The good news is that what you are wanting to do is very common, it is called "proxying". I believe that godaddy uses apache so specifically you will want to look for mod_rewrite. You will more than likely simply have to provide a .htaccess file with the rewrite rules in it.

Here are the gotchas that you will run into though:

1. Client hits www.company.com
2. www.company.com pulls content from www.anotherserver.com
3. www.company.com sends content back to the client.

The issues come in with the data that www.anotherserver.com sends back to the client. Enter the world of relative and absolute paths.

Let's say that the actual request is www.company.com/widget:

1. Client hits www.company.com/widget
2. www.company.com requests www.anotherserver.com/widget
3. www.anotherserver.com/widget returns a page but on that page it has a link to www.anotherserver.com/widget/image.jpg
4. www.company.com returns the content back to the client but now the client has a link to www.anotherserver.com/widget/image.jpg

You will need to make sure that your backend servers use relative paths instead of absolute paths. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)